# How we can get permission Id from a google drive api using PHP?

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api

I want a permission Id to update my user permissions of a file in google drive using google drive api with PHP.Can anybody tell me how to fetch the permission Id from response.
I went through this https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/update.
In this I need permission Id to update my permission but I am unable to get it. Can anybody tell me how i can fetch it programatically using PHP. What exact method is there to get the permission Id.

Comment: If you could edit you question to include what you have attempted so far that is not working please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to retrieve the permission ID from the file on Google Drive, you can retrieve it using the method of "Permissions: list" of Drive API.

#### Sample script 1:

From your provided URL, if you are using Drive API v2, you can use the following script.

```php
$fileId = "###"; // Please set the file ID.

$drive = new Google_Service_Drive($client); // Please use your authorization script.
$res = $drive->permissions->listPermissions($fileId);
$permissions = $res->getItems();
foreach ($permissions as &$p) {
    $id = $p->getId();
    print($id . "\n");
}
```

#### Sample script 2:

If you are using Drive API v3, you can use the following script.

```php
$fileId = "###"; // Please set the file ID.

$drive = new Google_Service_Drive($client); // Please use your authorization script.
$res = $drive->permissions->listPermissions($fileId);
$permissions = $res->getPermissions();
foreach ($permissions as &$p) {
    $id = $p->getId();
    print($id . "\n");
}
```

#### References:

- [Permissions: list of Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/list)
- [Permissions: list of Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list)